# Behavior of numpy.swapaxes

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone please explain the following behavior of numpy.swapaxes:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

n = 10 # Works fine, but doesn't if set n = 100
x = rand.uniform(size=(n, n, n))
x0 = deepcopy(x)
x += np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)  # Works fine if do x = x + np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1) instead...
temp = x0 + np.swapaxes(x0, 0, 1)
print np.linalg.norm(x - temp)
```

The printed error is zero when `n = 10`, but not when `n = 1000`. Why is this so? The code also works fine if we do `x = x + np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)` instead of `x += np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)`. (It has been quite frustrating to debug, since the code works on small samples...)

Comment: I can't explain the exact results that you are seeing, but the difference between `x += np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)` and `x = x + np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)` is easily explained by noting that `np.swapaxes` returns a _view_.  So in the case of `x += np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)`, you are writing to the same memory buffer that you are reading from.

Comment: That kind of buffering issue depends on the array size.  It can work on small arrays that fit in the buffer, but fail for arrays that fill the buffer(s) several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arise because you modify data you are reading ...

You will understand the problem [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5241).

Some extracts:

- This is a design issue, not really a bug.
- Numpy's general philosophy is to provide as much safety as possible without
  compromising on speed.
- [Correcting that] ... will cause unpredictable slowdowns and increased
  memory use in situations that are already well defined and work correctly.

Wisdom Rule :  NEVER modify data you are reading.